# Listen for All Events in Symfony 2

Tags: php, events, symfony

Is it possible to setup an event listener (or do — something else?) to listen for **all** the events fired by a Symfony 2 `AppKernel` application for a particular request?

That is, I know I can browse an application with `app_dev.php` and use the profiler to view a list of all the *listeners*, but I'm interested in grabbing a list of every event that's been dispatched/fired.  I know some event systems have a special global/all listener what would let me receive every event.  I'm wondering if Symfony has something similar, or if there's another mechanism to get a list of all the available events on a particular page.

I also know I could add some temporary debugging code to one of the event dispatcher classes

```
Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php
Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ContainerAwareTraceableEventDispatcher.php
Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php
```

but I'm looking for something that is less of a hack/less-destructive.

New to Symfony, but not new to programming.  Apologies if this is a naive question, but googling about hasn't revealed what I'm after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clean way would be creating your own EventDispatcher which executes your logging or whatever you're trying to do if an event occurs. Have a look at the [default one](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php) to get an idea of how it works.

Now first create the class

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;

class MyDispatcher extends EventDispatcher
{

    // sadly those properties aren't protected in EventDispatcher
    private $listeners = array();
    private $sorted = array();


    public function dispatch($eventName, Event $event = null)
    {
        if (null === $event) {
            $event = new Event();
        }

        $event->setDispatcher($this);
        $event->setName($eventName);

        // do something with the event here ... i.e. log it

        if (!isset($this->listeners[$eventName])) {
            return $event;
        }

        $this->doDispatch($this->getListeners($eventName), $eventName, $event);

        return $event;
    }
```

... then register your MyDispatcher as symfony's default one.

( by overwriting the original event_dispatcher service )

**app/config/config.yml**

```
services:
    event_dispatcher:
        class: Vendor\YourBundle\MyDispatcher
        arguments: [@service_container]
```

... or even simpler just override the [class parameter](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/services.xml#L18) being used by symfony when creating the service.

```
parameters:
    event_dispatcher.class: Vendor\YourBundle\MyDispatcher
```

Comment: Thanks — that's exactly what I was looking for. One follow up question that's mostly off topic but tangential.  Will my bundle automatically look for `config_prod.yml`, `config_dev.yml`, etc, or would it be up to me to make my bundle do this?

Comment: you have to tell your bundles which config files to load inside the bundle's extension found in <bundle>/DependencyInjection/BundleNameExtension.php. This file's `load()` method will be auto-executed by symfony if the file is named correctly. There is no environment-specific logic in there naturally